# Qt6 Google Sign-In API - How to manage redirect uri on mobile?

Tags: android, ios, google-oauth, google-signin, qt6

The block of code below is fully functional in qt6 (qt6.4.3 to be specific) for desktop and quasi-functional for mobile.  The redirect seems to get hung up on mobile; however, if the user manually switches back to the phone; the flow completes and the user information is obtained (in the example images, you can see the user email being displayed after authentication which has been parsed from the API reply).  I can see plenty of apps out there that do not require an extra step, so what exactly am I missing here?[Manually Switching back to app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s088U.jpg)  [Data displayed after api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTlrg.jpg)

Thank you in advance!!

```
QString clientId = "CLIENT ID FROM API CREDENTIALS";
QString authUri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
QString tokenUri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
QStringList redirectUris;
    redirectUris << "http://127.0.0.1:54321/"; //ensure this is included in the API credentials under authorized URI
    QString redirectUri = redirectUris[0];
    QString clientSecret = "YOUR CLIENT SECRET FROM API CREDENTIALS";
    auto google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow(this);
    google->setScope("email");
    google->setAuthorizationUrl(authUri);
    google->setClientIdentifier(clientId);
    google->setAccessTokenUrl(tokenUri);
    google->setClientIdentifierSharedKey(clientSecret);

    // Use the same port number as above
    auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(54321, this);
    google->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);

    // Set up the function to modify AND REPLACE the parameters
    google->setModifyParametersFunction([](QAbstractOAuth::Stage stage, QMultiMap<QString, QVariant>* parameters) {
        if (stage == QAbstractOAuth::Stage::RequestingAccessToken) {
            auto encodedCode = parameters->value("code").toByteArray();
            parameters->replace("code", QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(encodedCode));
        }
    });

    // Connect the signals to retrieve the tokens, if you want to see them
    connect(google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::tokenChanged, [=](const QString &token)
            {
                qDebug() << "Token changed:" << token;

            });
    connect(replyHandler, &QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler::tokensReceived, [](const QVariantMap &tokens)
            {
                qDebug() << "Tokens received:" << tokens;
            });

    connect(google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser, &QDesktopServices::openUrl);

    // Once you are granted access, make a request via the Google API
    connect(google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, [=]
            {
                qDebug() << "in the granted block now";
                // This block is run once you have logged into the browser successfully

                auto rep = google->get(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json"));
                QEventLoop loop;
                connect(rep, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
                loop.exec();
                QString currentByteArray = rep->readAll();
                qDebug() << "network reply google api connect step get info" << currentByteArray;

            });

    google->grant();
```

At end goal is a flawless google sign-in flow without additional steps from the user on mobile